# Vapor JSON from `[String: Any]` Dictionary

Tags: json, swift, vapor

If I build a Swift dictionary, i.e. `[String: Any]` how can I return that as JSON? I tried this, but it gives me the error: `Argument labels '(node:)' do not match any available overloads`.

```
drop.get("test") { request in
    var data: [String: Any] = [:]

    data["name"] = "David"
    data["state"] = "CA"

    return try JSON(node: data)
}
```

Comment: You have no method named JSON with a first parameter named node. If JSON is a class then it has no init method with a first parameter named node.

Comment: Easier: let data = ["name": "David", "state": "CA"]

Comment: JSON has an init method with `node`: https://vapor.github.io/documentation/guide/json.html#response

Answer (score 2):

Convoluted as heck, but this allows you to use [String:Any].makeNode(), as long as the internals are NodeRepresentable, NSNumber based, or NSNull :) --

```
import Node

enum NodeConversionError : LocalizedError {
    case invalidValue(String,Any)
    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .invalidValue(let key, let value): return "Value for \(key) is not NodeRepresentable - " + String(describing: type(of: value))
        }
    }
}

extension NSNumber : NodeRepresentable {
    public func makeNode(context: Context = EmptyNode) throws -> Node {
        return Node.number(.double(Double(self)))
    }
}

extension NSString : NodeRepresentable {
    public func makeNode(context: Context = EmptyNode) throws -> Node {
        return Node.string(String(self))
    }
}

extension KeyAccessible where Key == String, Value == Any {
    public func makeNode(context: Context = EmptyNode) throws -> Node {
        var mutable: [String : Node] = [:]
        try allItems.forEach { key, value in
            if let _ = value as? NSNull {
                mutable[key] = Node.null
            } else {
                guard let nodeable = value as? NodeRepresentable else { throw NodeConversionError.invalidValue(key, value) }
                mutable[key] = try nodeable.makeNode()
            }
        }
        return .object(mutable)
    }

    public func converted<T: NodeInitializable>(to type: T.Type = T.self) throws -> T {
        return try makeNode().converted()
    }
}
```

With that header you can:

```
return try JSON(node: data.makeNode())
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON cannot be initialized from a `[String : Any]` dictionary because `Any` is not convertible to `Node`.

There are only a limited number of types that Node can be. ([See Node source](https://github.com/vapor/node/tree/master/Sources/Node/Convertibles)). If you know your objects are all going to be the same type, use a dictionary that only allows that type. So for your example, `[String : String]`.

If you're going to be getting data from the request, you can try using `request.json` as is used in the documentation [here](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/guide/json.html#json-only).

## EDIT:

Another (possibly better) solution would be to make your dictionary `[String: Node]` and then you can include any type that conforms to `Node`. You may have to call the object's `makeNode()` function to add it to the dictionary though.

Comment: Still no solution for this?